# Make the children of DataTemplate inherit color of parents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I've got a DataTemplate for ListViewItems with some TextBoxes and Combos within. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
        <Border Margin="2, 2, 4, 2" BorderThickness="2, 0, 0, 0">
            <Grid>
                (...)
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="hoursField" Margin="5">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Hours" />
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
 ...
```

Now, I want to make the TextBox to inherit the background color of his container, in order to be draw with the same background color of the StackPanel, and change the Foreground of the TextBoxes to white every time ListView is selected.

Any clue on how I can obtain this?

Comment: Doesn't it do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around with anything other than the controls you are adding, set their background colour to be transparent.

Hacky, but will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your questions are :

a.) I want to make the TextBox to inherit the background color of his container.

Answer: you need to set a background color of the root grid for the ListBoxItem ControlTemplate. This will be inherited by the content presenters placed inside the ListBoxItem.

b.) change the Foreground of the TextBoxes to white every time ListView is selected

Answer: in the ListBoxItem ControlTemplate change the foreground of the root grid to be white in the selected state

Answer (score 0):

If your background color of the parent changes, you can also use binding to explicitly tell the text box to bind the containing control, using the ElementName within the binding.